# Which of the following subsets of   $\mathbb{R}^2$ are compact

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are compact?

- (a) $\left\{ (x, y) : xy = 1 \right\} $
- (b) $\left\{ (x, y) : x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1 \right\}$
- (c) $\left\{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1\right\}$

clearly a and c are not compact. not sure about b

Comment: Do you know the characterization of compact subsets of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the set bounded? For all $x\in\Bbb R$, $x^{2/3}\ge 0$, so if $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$, how big can $x$ and $y$ be?

Is it closed? That’s harder to answer rigorously, but a glance at the graph of the expression should give you a pretty good idea.

Comment: $f:(x,y)\mapsto x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}$ is continuous so $f^{-1}(1)$ is closed.

Comment: @Sriti: Yes, if one knows that fact about continuous functions, there’s an easy way to justify the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

a) closed but unbounded so not compact.

b) closed and bounded.[image: see the graph]

c) Open set.